# is there's a way to make SFML Event MouseButtonPressed work after one click?

Tags: sfml

so I am trying to make a small game using sfml but I am stuck at MouseButton event I try to choose from the menu I has to spam clicks for it to work I thought the problem was my mouse so I tried another one and it didn't solve the problem

```
void draw(sf::RenderWindow &window)
{
    mousePos = window.mapPixelToCoords(sf::Mouse::getPosition(window));
    window.draw(Background_rect);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        window.draw(rect[i]);
        if (rect[i].getGlobalBounds().contains(mousePos))
        {
            while (window.pollEvent(event))
            {
                if (event.type == sf::Event::MouseButtonPressed && event.mouseButton.button == sf::Mouse::Left)
                {
                    mainMenuPress = mainMenuSelected[i];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

so i think the code is good but I don't understand why it doesn't work after 1 click

Comment: Can you edit your question to explain what doesn’t work? Do you get an error message or what? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: no the code compile perfectly the problem is that the event mouse button pressed doesn't work after 1 click that's it i don't make a game for the user to spam clicks for the button to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i couldn't solve it as event mouseButtonPressed i don't know what's the problem with event type but it didn't work for me i had to change the condition as mouse isButtonPressed and it worked

```
void draw(sf::RenderWindow &window)
{
    mousePos = window.mapPixelToCoords(sf::Mouse::getPosition(window));
    
    window.draw(Background_rect);

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        if (rect[i].getGlobalBounds().contains(mousePos))
        {
            if (sf::Mouse::isButtonPressed(sf::Mouse::Left))  //Changed
            {
                mainMenuPress = mainMenuSelected[i];
            }
        }
        window.draw(rect[i]);
    }
}
```

thanks for your help

Answer (score -1):

As you have shown more code, I thing this for loop might ba the problem -
you should move pollEvent to the place where you update any stuff, and then make any ifs and loops inside it

```
// in update
while (window.pollEvent(event))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        if (event.type == sf::Event::MouseButtonPressed && event.mouseButton.button == sf::Mouse::Left)
        {
            if (rect[i].getGlobalBounds().contains(mousePos))
            {
                mainMenuPress = mainMenuSelected[i];
            }
        }
    }
}

// and then draw
```

Comment: thanks for your answer it helped but didn't solve the problem now rather than spaming for  it to work it takes 1 to 5 clicks to work and i changed the code please check it

Comment: So I think the problem here is this for loop. Try to move any events to the place where you are updating everything (I'd make it before drawing). Make one pollEvent there and check inside it any if statements and do any for loops.

Comment: not the problem i have tried it but it didn't solve the problem